# how to use printf("%sd",x) instead of printf("%5d",x) in C. Here s = 5

Tags: c, format

So i really want this to happen. I have an integer variable and i want to use that variable to give spacing in my printf function but C doesn't give me permission to do that , is there any way around it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
   int s = 5;
   printf("%sd",s);
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You mean if s=5 you want output '     5' ? if 2  output should be '  2' ?

Answer (score 7):

The * in a format specifier means "I'll pass this number as an argument."

```
int s = 5;
printf("--%*d", s, s);
```

output

```
--    5
```

Nice page with details here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm

Answer (score 5):

Using `*` for the width will cause `printf` to take the width from the next argument, which should have type `int`:

```
printf("%*d", s, ValueToBePrinted);
```

You can find information about `printf` and other C features in [the C standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents). In the C 2011 version, formatted I/O is covered in clause 7.21, about `<stdio.h>`. 7.21.6.1 discusses `fprintf`, which uses the same format syntax as `printf` and is referred to from the `printf` clause, 7.21.6.3. Paragraph 5 discusses using `*` for a field width.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by spacing here ? You can simply put ‘\t’ before ‘%d’ to give a tab before printing the value of the variable. Also ‘%sd’ doesn’t mean anything. Here %d is replaced by the value of your variable stated after the comma, ie, in your case it’s variable s.

Comment: You should read the Question, the other Answers too and more over, after you are done reading, then you should read Printf’s manual. After that you should edit or delete your Answer.